# Update from statement in hive

Tags: hive

I have 2 tables with identical schemas in hive.

```
tbl1(a,b,c)
tbl2(a,b,c)
```

I want to update tbl1 as follows

```
update x from tbl1 x,tbl2 y
set   x.c=y.c
where x.a=y.a
and   x.b=y.b
```

But this didn't run on hive.
Whats the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment.

Hive does not support updating one table using values from another (at least with the `update` statement).

The [syntax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Update) for the statement is:

```
UPDATE tablename
    SET column = value [, column = value ...]
   [WHERE expression]
```

In particular, `value` cannot be a subquery:

> The value assigned must be an expression that Hive supports in the
>   select clause.  Thus arithmetic operators, UDFs, casts, literals, etc.
>   are supported.  Subqueries are not supported.

Do note that subqueries are allowed in the `where` clause.

Comment: so how can we achieve this in an efficient way?

Comment: If you are updating basically all the rows, then one option is to write a query to create a new table.

Comment: I am updating only those rows whose a,b columns are also in tbl2 i.e. x.a=y.a and   x.b=y.b